# Can not add in a span,value of struts2 iteration

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I have a list values with struts 2 iteration.I want to list values of tags in a span,for example:Tags:`Java`,`Hibernate`,`Struts2`.My values it is displaying like :

```
Tags:
Java,
Hibernate,
Struts2.
```

I haven't good excperience in css and I am not clearly for this.This is the reason can't not find solution by searching.
How to Add in a span value of tags name while struts2 iteration?Thanks!

index.jsp

```
  <span>
Tag:    
<s:if test="listTag.size() > 0">
<s:iterator value="listTag" status="status" id="target">
<article class="blog-item <s:if test="#status.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">

  <h2 class="blog-title">
    <s:url id="idUrl" action=""><s:param name="id"><s:property value="id" /></s:param></s:url>
     <s:a href="%{idUrl}" style="color: #3071A9"><s:property value="name" /></s:a>
     </h2>      


                </article>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:if>
    </span>
```

generated html

```
<span>
Tag:    


<article class="blog-item odd">

  <h2 class="blog-title">

     <a href="/blog/.html?id=6" style="color: #3071A9">struts2</a>
     </h2>      


                </article>

<article class="blog-item even">

  <h2 class="blog-title">

     <a href="/blog/.html?id=5" style="color: #3071A9">name</a>
     </h2>      


                </article>

<article class="blog-item odd">

  <h2 class="blog-title">

     <a href="/blog/.html?id=4" style="color: #3071A9">java</a>
     </h2>      


                </article>


    </span>
```

Comment: Please post your generated html (view source)

Comment: Ahah, there you go ! You have added tons of HTML in the source, that clearly explains why they're on different lines. They're block-level elements, to set them inline use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` on them. Also consider avoiding using the <article> tag, that is a container, to just keep an inline value... BTW the rule is: `h2, article{display: inline-block;}`

Comment: Thank you very much!It works!You have also helped to other questions that i have searched for!Sorry for my low css excperience!